# How to make a boolean index in numpy for multiple integer types without a loop

Tags: numpy

I would like to create a boolean index of an array that has true values whenever any integers in a given list appear in the array.  Right now I do this by looping through the list of test integers and constructing a seperate boolean mask for each which I bitwise `or` together like this:

```
boolean_mask = original_array == list_of_codes[0]
for code in list_of_codes[1::]:
    boolean_mask = boolean_mask | (original_array == code)
```

Is there any shorthand numpy notation to do the equivalent without the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
boolean_mask = np.in1d(original_array, list_of_codes)
```

should do it. Note that `np.in1d` flattens both arrays, so if your `original_array` is multidimensional you will have to reshape it back, e.g.:

```
boolean_mask = boolean_mask.reshape(original_array.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) will let you just write:

```
boolean_mask = (original_array == list_of_codes)
```

If this is wrong please give a small test example so I can make sure I know what you're trying to do.

Comment: That won't work. You could do something along the lines of `np.logical_or.reduce(original_array[..., np.newaxis] == list_of_codes, axis=-1)`, but it can create a huge intermediate array, depending on the size of `list_of_codes`, so performance would probably not be too good.

Comment: @Jamie's answer np.in1d works, your example gives 'False'.  Here's an example:  np.array([0,1,2,3,4]) == [1,2] I want to yield [False, True, True, False, False], but the example yields just False.